# Force open qr code URL to open in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari, qr-code

I am a web designer, and hosted a webpage, which contain some photos.

I've made a qr code link to the webpage. For the chrome and safari, we can hold a finger on the photo then save it, but the problem is what ever I scan a qr code, user which default use the in-app browser, which can't save photo to the photo, I think the only way to solve it, is to force the user open out of in-app browser, once I've found chrome's URL scheme like chrome:// can work for it, but are there any for safari? or are there any way to force user to open that qr code in browser not in-app browser?

Thanks for your kind help.